# gSOAP communication is always interrupted

Tags: c++, gsoap

I am trying to test my proxy object and connecting to server, but somehow it's not receiving response at all. After I spent a day googling around I did not find anything related to the issue.

```
Error -1 fault at source [no subcode]
"End of file or no input: message transfer interrupted or timed out (30 s recv delay) (30 s send delay)"
Detail: [no detail]
```

The main issue seems to be this line, which is weird. Not sure how to find the culprit. It seems like it's been cut off somewhere between the gSOAP and the network while trying to read.

```
Read 0 bytes from socket=7/fd=0
```

(via homebrew: gSoap 2.8.28, OpenSSL 1.0.2h_1. OS X 10.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: don't touch the undocumented file pointers that are in gSOAP structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check the service endpoint URL that your proxy uses to verify that it points to the correct service port. You can specify an endpoint URL as a proxy constructor parameter string or you can set the soap_endpoint member string. Also, try different service operations to see if the problem is connectivity or is related to a specific SOAP/REST operation, or perhaps is just an intermittent TCP/IP connectivity issue. In that case a TCP/IP data logger can be helpful.